# Node.js ursa installation errors: C2039, C2504, C4430 and C2143

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, npm

I am trying to install Node.js Ursa module but it shows the error below:

```
> ursa@0.8.1 install C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master
> node-gyp configure && node-gyp build && node install.js


C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" configure
child_process: customFds option is deprecated, use stdio instead.

C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" build
child_process: customFds option is deprecated, use stdio instead.
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
  ursaNative.cc
  asprintf.cc
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(14): error C2039: 'ObjectWra
p' : is not a member of 'node' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ur
sa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(14): error C2504: 'ObjectWra
p' : base class undefined (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-ma
ster\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(22): error C2039: 'Arguments
' : is not a member of 'v8' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(22): error C4430: missing ty
pe specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\ursa
Native.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(22): error C2143: syntax err
or : missing ',' before '&' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(23): error C2039: 'Arguments
' : is not a member of 'v8' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(23): error C4430: missing ty
pe specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\ursa
Native.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(23): error C2143: syntax err
or : missing ',' before '&' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(24): error C2039: 'Arguments
' : is not a member of 'v8' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(24): error C4430: missing ty
pe specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\ursa
Native.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(24): error C2143: syntax err
or : missing ',' before '&' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(25): error C2039: 'Arguments
' : is not a member of 'v8' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(25): error C4430: missing ty
pe specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\ursa
Native.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(25): error C2143: syntax err
or : missing ',' before '&' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(26): error C2039: 'Arguments
' : is not a member of 'v8' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(26): error C4430: missing ty
pe specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\ursa
Native.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(26): error C2143: syntax err
or : missing ',' before '&' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(27): error C2039: 'Arguments
' : is not a member of 'v8' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(27): error C4430: missing ty
pe specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\ursa
Native.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(27): error C2143: syntax err
or : missing ',' before '&' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(28): error C2039: 'Arguments
' : is not a member of 'v8' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(28): error C4430: missing ty
pe specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\ursa
Native.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(28): error C2143: syntax err
or : missing ',' before '&' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(29): error C2039: 'Arguments
' : is not a member of 'v8' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(29): error C4430: missing ty
pe specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\ursa
Native.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(29): error C2143: syntax err
or : missing ',' before '&' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(30): error C2039: 'Arguments
' : is not a member of 'v8' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(30): error C4430: missing ty
pe specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\ursa
Native.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(30): error C2143: syntax err
or : missing ',' before '&' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(31): error C2039: 'Arguments
' : is not a member of 'v8' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(31): error C4430: missing ty
pe specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\ursa
Native.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(31): error C2143: syntax err
or : missing ',' before '&' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(32): error C2039: 'Arguments
' : is not a member of 'v8' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(32): error C4430: missing ty
pe specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\ursa
Native.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(32): error C2143: syntax err
or : missing ',' before '&' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(33): error C2039: 'Arguments
' : is not a member of 'v8' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(33): error C4430: missing ty
pe specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\ursa
Native.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(33): error C2143: syntax err
or : missing ',' before '&' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(34): error C2039: 'Arguments
' : is not a member of 'v8' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(34): error C4430: missing ty
pe specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\ursa
Native.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(34): error C2143: syntax err
or : missing ',' before '&' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(35): error C2039: 'Arguments
' : is not a member of 'v8' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(35): error C4430: missing ty
pe specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\ursa
Native.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(35): error C2143: syntax err
or : missing ',' before '&' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(36): error C2039: 'Arguments
' : is not a member of 'v8' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(36): error C4430: missing ty
pe specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\ursa
Native.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(36): error C2143: syntax err
or : missing ',' before '&' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(37): error C2039: 'Arguments
' : is not a member of 'v8' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(37): error C4430: missing ty
pe specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\ursa
Native.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(37): error C2143: syntax err
or : missing ',' before '&' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(40): error C2039: 'Arguments
' : is not a member of 'v8' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(40): error C4430: missing ty
pe specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\ursa
Native.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(40): error C2143: syntax err
or : missing ',' before '&' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(41): error C2039: 'Arguments
' : is not a member of 'v8' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(41): error C4430: missing ty
pe specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\ursa
Native.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(41): error C2143: syntax err
or : missing ',' before '&' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(42): error C2039: 'Arguments
' : is not a member of 'v8' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(42): error C4430: missing ty
pe specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\ursa
Native.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(42): error C2143: syntax err
or : missing ',' before '&' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(47): error C2039: 'Arguments
' : is not a member of 'v8' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(47): error C4430: missing ty
pe specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (..\src\ursa
Native.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\ursa-master\src\ursaNative.h(47): error C2143: syntax err
or : missing ',' before '&' (..\src\ursaNative.cc) [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-
master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
..\src\ursaNative.cc(42): error C2039: 'NewSymbol' : is not a member of 'v8::St
ring' [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
          C:\Users\User\.node-gyp\0.12.0\deps\v8\include\v8.h(1599) : see decla
  ration of 'v8::String'
..\src\ursaNative.cc(42): error C2664: 'v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> v8::Fun
ctionTemplate::New(v8::Isolate *,v8::FunctionCallback,v8::Handle<v8::Value>,v8:
:Handle<v8::Signature>,int)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'v8::Handle<v8::V
alue> (__cdecl *)(const int)' to 'v8::Isolate *' [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-ma
ster\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
          There is no context in which this conversion is possible
..\src\ursaNative.cc(42): error C2227: left of '->GetFunction' must point to cl
ass/struct/union/generic type [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNati
ve.vcxproj]
..\src\ursaNative.cc(42): error C3861: 'NewSymbol': identifier not found [C:\Us
ers\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
..\src\ursaNative.cc(71): error C2039: 'New' : is not a member of 'v8::String'
[C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
          C:\Users\User\.node-gyp\0.12.0\deps\v8\include\v8.h(1599) : see decla
  ration of 'v8::String'
..\src\ursaNative.cc(71): error C3861: 'New': identifier not found [C:\Users\Us
er\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
..\src\ursaNative.cc(74): error C3861: 'ThrowException': identifier not found [
C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
..\src\ursaNative.cc(83): error C2039: 'New' : is not a member of 'v8::String'
[C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
          C:\Users\User\.node-gyp\0.12.0\deps\v8\include\v8.h(1599) : see decla
  ration of 'v8::String'
..\src\ursaNative.cc(83): error C3861: 'ThrowException': identifier not found [
C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
..\src\ursaNative.cc(83): error C3861: 'New': identifier not found [C:\Users\Us
er\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
..\src\ursaNative.cc(93): error C2882: 'Buffer' : illegal use of namespace iden
tifier in expression [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNative.vcxpro
j]
..\src\ursaNative.cc(93): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous er
ror(s); stopping compilation [C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\build\ursaNativ
e.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe` fail
ed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1067
:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! ursa@0.8.1 install: `node-gyp configure && node-gyp build && node insta
ll.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ursa@0.8.1 install script 'node-gyp configure && node-gyp
 build && node install.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the ursa package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp configure && node-gyp build && node install.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ursa
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\Desktop\ursa-master\npm-debug.log
```

I don't have Visual studio 2010, only 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I just downgrade the version of my Node.js, and it's working!